# Notification doesn't show up on Redmi 8 MIUI 11 and 12

Tags: notifications, push-notifications

Some push notification from some apps (some games actually, I wasn't aware about other apps) suddenly no longer appeared. When I first bought this phone, they all worked fine, but then I updated MIUI to 11 and 12, and since then notification from games wouldn't appear. They would only appear when:

1. I opened the said games
2. In battery-saving mode (on low battery, when I activated this mode, notifs will immediately popped up)

I have turned on notification in Settings for those apps, doesn't help.

Anyone encountered the same problem? Any solution?

My device:
Redmi Note 8 Pro, Android 10 (Q), MIUI Global 12.0.2 Stable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is usually a problem with battery optimization. Go to your settings and identify the list under battery optimization (that is the stock Android name, it could be battery saver etc). Remove those apps from the list

Edit: As confirmed by OP in [comment](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/231567/notification-doesnt-show-up-on-redmi-8-miui-11-and-12#comment304424_231578), it is found under Settings → Battery & performance → App battery saver. Selecting those app(s) from the list, and changing from `Battery Saver` to `No restrictions` fixed the problem of missing notifications.

Comment: Currently in my device (MIUI 12), the setting is in `Settings > Battery & performance > App battery saver`. Select the troubled app from the list, and change from `Battery Saver`  to `No restrictions`, and finally the notifications appear. Again, thank you very much!